# MongoDB not returning data using NodeJS driver application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using mongoose to connect mongoDB. Its a nodeJS application. Right now I'm concerned to get the data and display it in my application. However, it doesn't show any error, neither it displays any data.
Here's my server file

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('./DB');

const employeeRoute = require('./routes/employee.route');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(config.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => { console.log('Database is connected') },
        err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database' + err) }
    );

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/Employees', employeeRoute);
let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
})
```

and here's my `route` file

```
const express = require('express');
const employeeRoute = express.Router();

let Employees = require('../models/Employee');

employeeRoute.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    let employees = [];
    Employees.find({}, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            employees = results;
            console.log(employees)
            res.json(employees);
        }
    })
})
module.exports = employeeRoute
```

and lastly my `employee.js` file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Employee = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    title: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    location: { type: String },
    phone: { type: Number }
},
    { collation: 'Employees' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employees', Employee)
```

Application runs fine without any error. Before posting it to the forum, I've double checked the `db` and `collection` names.
any suggestions

Comment: is `useNewUrlPars` the correct option term? Shouldn't it be `useNewUrlParser` ? - just reading through the rest now.

Comment: does you console shows 'Database is connected' if yes, make sure you are connected to correct database. can you go and check if you have records in your Employee document. Sometimes the problem is very tiny but we think its huge.

Comment: yes it shows `Database is connected` and I also ensured that I have data in my collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might just need to refactor your route a little bit in order to ensure you get the results you want. For example, take a look at my following example:

```
const express = require('express');
const employeeRoute = express.Router();

let Employees = require('../models/Employee');

employeeRoute.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
  // Extract data from the request object here in order to search for employees. For example:
  const name = req.body.name;
  const surname = req.body.surname;

  let employees = [];

  // Now perform a find on your specific data:
  Employees.find({ first_name: name, last_name: surname }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else employees = results; 

    console.log(JSON.stringify(employees));
    res.json(employees);
  });

  // Or you can perform a find on all employees
  Employees.find({}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else employees = results; 

    console.log(JSON.stringify(employees));
    res.json(employees);
  });

})
module.exports = employeeRoute
```

As I mentioned in my comment too, your connection may need to be changed to use the correct term: `useNewUrlParser`

**EDIT**

I also noticed that in your Employee Schema, you put `collation` instead of `collection` - see below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Employee = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    title: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    location: { type: String },
    phone: { type: Number }
}, { collection: 'employees' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Employees', Employee)
```

Try that, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong buddy.Here's a sample way of inserting data using mongoose.

```
employeeRoute.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
        Employees.create({your_data}) // ex: {email:req.body.email}
              .then((employee)=>{
                   console.log(employee)
                   res.json(employee);
               }).catch((err)=> {
                   console.log(err);
                   res.status(400).send({message: "your message"})
               })

})
module.exports = employeeRoute
```

Comment: I want to `read` the data from database not `insert` buddy, thanks. Looking at your code now

Comment: let emp = new Employees(res); console.log(res);
this line made me confused!!

Comment: I've updated the code in question, please look at that now

Comment: first of all make sure that your app can conncet to mongo.
mongoose.connect(config.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then( () => { console.log('Database is connected') })
    .catch( err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database' + err) })

Comment: and make sure, actually you have data in employees collection

Comment: yes, I've check both of the things,  `have data in Employees collection` and `database connection is also successfull`

Comment: how about console.log(results)

Comment: displays nothing, seems like its not even reaching the statement `console.log(results)`

Comment: then you gotta figure that why, i am seeing no problem in current code

Comment: that's the actual problem, because I'm following the tutorial and he has the same code as mines, I don't know why his code works and mine do not